# When we are trying to convert .psd image to png we are getting a very long time. using Image magic SDK

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, developer-tools

When we are trying to convert .psd image to png we are getting a very long time.
Detail of PSD
-Image disk size: 48.3 MB
-Dimensions: 1300 × 1152
-No of Layer: Layer 41 copy, Layer 45 copy, Layer 43 copy, Layer 47 copy, Layer 37 copy, headlight_reflection, headlight_reflection2, headlight_reflection4, ptc-master-KO_GR, LIGHTEXTURE_3, shadow copy 3, and 13 more
Colour space: RGB instead of CMYK
Image Magic Version: 6.7.7.10-6
OS: ubuntu 3.13
Note: If we change Colour space RGB to CMYK than this is taking very less time.

PSD to PNG image taking very long time when Colour space RGB #2246

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and format it properly. Indent code by 4 spaces at the start of the line. In the meantime, your ImageMagick is around 5 years out of date and your Ubuntu is prehistoric... time to upgrade... it's free ;-)

Comment: I do not think anyone can help you unless you post your PSD file.

Comment: Also tell us what your exact ImageMagick version is.